# How to handle mongoose connection delay in node acl

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, acl

I am implementing acl usind node_acl for my express app.
I am making db connection in a separate file to handle the connection time of mongoose like this:
connect.js:

```
const   mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = function initConnection(callback) {
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/aclExample', {});
    var db = mongoose.connection;
    db1 = mongoose.connection.db;
    db.on('error', function (err) {
      console.error('Failed to connect to database');
      process.exit(1);
    });

    db.once('open', function () {
      console.info("Connected to database");
      callback(db1);
      console.log('acl is now set');
    });
};
```

and including it in the app.js to create acl object like this

```
var node_acl = require('acl');
var connectACL = require('@root/fe-server/middlewares/fe.middleware.acl.js');
connectACL(function(db){
acl = new node_acl(new node_acl.mongodbBackend(db, 'acl_'));
});
console.log('ACL: ',acl);
```

the problem is that console.log is executing before database connection is established. How can I handle this? I have to use acl in my app.js and other files for route authorization so using it inside callbacks always doesn't make sense.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can promisify acl creation, or move it to some kind of initialization layer.

```
  const promise = new Promise(resolve => connectACL(resolve));
  promise.then(db => { 
    return new new node_acl.mongodbBackend(db, 'acl_')
  })
  .then(acl => {
     APP.setAcl(acl);
     APP.bootsrtap()
  })

  //or with node 7.8+
  (async (){
        const db = await new Promise(resolve => connectACL(resolve));
        const acl = new node_acl.mongodbBackend(db, 'acl_');
        application.bootstrapOrSomethingLikeThis()
  })()
```

Comment: what is APP.setAcl(acl)? I mean what is APP?